# Installshield and copying registry entries

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installshield

I have InstallShield which comes with Visual Studio 2012.

I need to make a copy of a registry entry and place it into a holder registry location.

The value of the registry needs to be saved in a different location when the application is installed.  The application, at run time, will go into the backup location and read the value, modify the contents, and save it back to the proper location.

**My question:**
Is there is a way to make a copy of a registry and place it in to another location using the InstallShield?

Answer (score 0):

If the registry entries in question exist before the installer is started and nothing in the installer is deleting the path the registry entries are in; you could use SystemSearch (appsearch) to populate some properties in your installer that you then write out to the the desired location.

It would be easier with a custom action though; easier to replicate a registry tree in c# or c++ than by manually searching for a bunch of registry entries.